# Azure Functions modify timetrigger interval when using CI

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Say I have a timetriggered function that should only run in production, or maybe have different schedule in production, how can I do that?

When using CI the the app goes into read-only mode, and timetrigger interval is not configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few options but I'd suggest you define your `TimerTrigger` to pick up it's schedule from the App Settings of the function app - where you can populate this via your CI process, or manually if need be.

Defining your function in C# in the VS 2017 tooling you need a method signature like this e.g.

```
[FunctionName("MyTimerFunction")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%TriggerInterval%")] TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

And in the function app settings (or `local.settings.json` to run locally) define the CRON interval for the timer.

```
{
"Values" : {
    "TriggerInterval": "0 0 * * * *" // e.g. hourly 
  }
}
```

Additionally, if you need a quick fix, even if your CI process has set the app the read-only mode, you can still set it to read/write and then update the settings - of course that will be overridden the next time the CI deploys to that function app.